# Does category theory provide a rigorous definition of the cartesian product?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. As far as I know, the defining property of the cartesian product
\begin{equation}
X\times Y=\left\{(x,y):x\in X\text{ and }y\in Y\right\}
\end{equation}
is the "universal property"
\begin{equation}
(x,y)=(x',y')\Leftrightarrow x=x'\text{ and }y=y'
\end{equation}
for all $x,x'\in X$ and $y,y'\in Y$. It is known that the definition $(x,y):=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ has the above property. But I guess this is only one of many possible definitions.

I have no background in category theory, but I got the impression that it is always needed to get the full picture when dealing with something that has a **universal property** (e.g. the tensor product), that's why I thought that it might help me get a more precise definition of the cartesian product.

If your answer contains terms specific to category theory, it would be much appreciated if you also gave some reference, so that I have a starting point for a rigorous introduction to the topic.

Comment: I believe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_(category_theory)#Examples) wikipedia entry has what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm not sure if "rigorous" is the appropriate word, since the definition of the cartesian product of sets is rigorous. However, the universal property (as linked in the previous comment) shows that it is a general definition suitable for contexts others than sets.

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba What do you mean by "the" definition of the cartesian product? $(x,y):=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$?

Comment: What you wrote is a definition of ordered pair. I mean $X\times Y=\{(x,y)\,\colon\,\dotso\}$

Answer (score 6):

The categorical version looks like this.  Let two sets $X,Y$ be given. A *product* of $X$ and $Y$ is  (1) a set $P$, (2) a map $\pi_X : P \to X$, (3) a map $\pi_Y : P\to Y$, such that:  For every set $Z$, and every pair of maps $f : Z \to X$, $g : Z \to Y$, there is a unique map $h : Z \to P$ such that $ f = \pi_X \circ h$ and $g = \pi_Y \circ h$.

One then proves the idea with ordered pairs does define such a product.  I that case $\pi_X(x,y) = x$, $\pi_Y(x,y) = y$, $h(x,y) = (f(x),g(x))$.

Comment: Isn't a map from $X$ to $Y$ usually defined as a subset $A\subset X\times Y$ with the property that for each $x\in X$ there is exactly one $y\in Y$ with the property $(x,y)\in A$? That is, to define maps we first need to define the cartesian product?

Comment: One can set up foundations so that functions are defined in terms of sets.  One can set up foundations so that sets are defined in terms of functions.  One can use category theory as a foundation for mathematics, not sets.  For most of mathematics, it is irrelevant what the "fundations" are.

Comment: @Filippo Another part of the answer to your concern is that the universal property characterized the Cartesian product, but does not construct it. At some point you have to actually construct the product, and there’s no reason not to do that before you’ve defined a function.

Comment: @GEdgar I have never seen the definition of sets in terms of functions, but that sounds interesting. Could you please explain that and/or give a reference?

Comment: Basically, your undefined concepts are functions and composition.  The define a **set** to be a function with values only  $0$ and $1$.  [Of course $0$ and $1$ are certain functions...] See "NBG set theory", nowadays formulated with sets and classes; but in von Neumann's original paper (in German) formulated with functions.  There is an English version, where did I see it?  Perhas van Heijenoort, *From Frege to Gödel*

Comment: As I already said, I regarded it as a problem that we need functions to formulate the universal property of the cartesian product, since we priorly need the cartesian product to define functions. However, I think I now understand why you said "product" instead of "cartesian product" in your answer and I'd say this also solves my "problem": We can regard the cartesian product $X\times Y$ (consisting of ordered pairs) as a tool to define functions from $X$ to $Y$ and after doing so, we can define a product of $X$ and $Y$ by a universal property the way you explained.

Comment: This is **not** a re-definition of the cartesian product, but as you said in your answer, the cartesian products $X\times Y$ and $Y\times X$ (together with the usual projections) turn out to be products of $X$ and $Y$. I think it's conceptually important to make this distinction, for example in physics, when we consider state spaces that are products of some sets.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different formulation of the universal property. It should be equivalent to the other answer in the sense that sets that have the following property also have the universal property described in the other answer and vice versa.

Consider a set $I$ and let $X_i$ be a set for all $i\in I$.
\begin{equation*}
    X:=\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i
\end{equation*}
Now, let $M$ be the set of all maps from $I$ to $X$ and
\begin{equation*}
    \mathcal{M}=\{x\in M:x_i\in X_i\text{ for all }i\in I\}.
\end{equation*}

---

A **Cartesian product** of the family $\{X_i:i\in I\}$ consists of a set $P$ and a family of maps $\{\pi_i\colon P\to X_i:i\in I\}$ such that the map $f\colon P\to\mathcal{M}$ that assigns to each $x\in P$ the map
\begin{align*}
    f(x)\colon I&\to X\\
    i&\mapsto\pi_i(x)
\end{align*}
is bijective. We identify $x\in P$ with $f(x)$.

---

Let $P$ to $P'$ be Cartesian products of $\{X_i:i\in I\}$. Then there is exactly one natural bijection from $P$ to $P'$:

According to the definition of Cartesian products, we can construct bijective maps $f\colon P\to\mathcal{M}$ and $f'\colon P'\to\mathcal{M}$. The map $f^{-1}\circ f'\colon P'\to P$ is the natural bijection that allows us to identify elements of $P$ and $P'$ that correspond the same element of $\mathcal{M}$: If $x'\in P'$ and $x=F(x')$, $f(x)=f'(x')\in\mathcal{M}$.

**Comment.** I think this is a very natural way to describe the universal property: It often happens that the Cartesian product is defined as $\mathcal{M}$, just like the tensor product is sometimes defined as the set of multilinear maps. In both cases, the universal property can be described making use of the "naive" definitions.