# Can we define the cartesian product by a universal property without involving (not yet defined) functions

Tags: set-theory

I know that set theory provides a definition of ordered tuples:
\begin{equation}
(x,y):=\big\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\big\}
\end{equation}
However, I think that this is just one of many possible definitions - for example, my guess would be that
\begin{equation}
(x,y):=\big\{\{x,y\},\{y\}\big\}
\end{equation}
is a "good" alternative definition.

This suggests that it should be possible to define the cartesian product by a universal property. This has already been done (e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3957287/does-category-theory-provide-a-rigorous-definition-of-the-cartesian-product)), but it involves functions, which we can only introduce after defining the cartesian product.

Comment: The (categorial) product involves an object and some morphisms, yes. Depending on what object you choose as a representative of this product (it is unique only up to isomorphism -if I remembeer correctly the isomorphism is also unique) you will get some family of maps. These maps are abstractions of the projections from the cartesian product, so this maps just tell you how to project the product onto each of its factors. Usually, given a construction of the product object, the projections are clear, but if they're not, they should be specified.

Answer (score 1):

A universal property characterizes an object up to a unique isomorphism, but it does not say that such an object exists. You still have to make some kind of construction to show that it does. What the universal property ensures is that all the different constructions will get you the same object (up to a unique isomorphism) so that, usually, you do not worry about the construction once you have done it once. But you still need to do it, one way or another ! Except of course if your category is defined by a set of axioms saying that such an object has to exist. But the usual axioms of set theory do not say that products need to exist, so you need to choose a way to construct them.

Comment: I understand, but can't we formulate a universal property and prove that the usual definition of the cartesian product has that property?

Comment: For example, my guess would be that if we are able to formulate such a universal property, the definition $(x,y):=\big\{\{x,y\},\{y\}\big\}$ would be a valid alternative definition.

Comment: There is such a universal property (that is, the set of such couples is a product in the category of sets) which does exactly that. I'm not entirely sure of what you are looking for there.

Comment: If I understand properly, you would like to state the universal property before doing the construction ? The problem is that from the ZF axioms, you don't get a category automatically, and I can't see how you could define functions from these axioms without having already constructed cartesian products. Again, there may be axioms better suited to get a category before constructing products, or even axioms assuming the existence of products, but the ZF axioms are not meant to do this.

Comment: You understand properly, that's exactly what I would like to do! I am an undergraduate student (currently writing my bachelor thesis) and unfortunately, we have never talked about categories and I'm not satisfied with the information I found online...

Comment: Anyways, as far as I understand, you think that we need another system of axioms - possibly with sets $\textbf{and}$ functions as [primitive notions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_notion#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20logic%2C%20philosophy%2C%20and%20formal%20systems%2C%20a,relations%20between%20primitive%20notions%20are%20restricted%20by%20axioms.) - as our foundation, right?

Comment: I do not think we need another system of axioms (ZFC is fine), but I think you would need another system of axioms if you want to do what you suggest. Maybe something like the way topos theory is looking at the category of sets. But I am not convinced this is really worth the effort (at least if your question is your only motivation).

Comment: However, if you want to read about category theory (which is totally worth the investment), Simmons' Introduction to Category Theory is really nice, starting from scratch. McLane's book is a bit more tough, but a good reference also.

Comment: Thank you very much for the references!

Comment: Here's what I currently consider the solution to my "problem": The cartesian product $X\times Y$ can be regarded as a tool to define functions from $X$ to $Y$ and after having introduced functions, we can define a product of $X$ and $Y$ by the universal property I mentioned in my question. It then turns out that the the cartesian products $X\times Y$ and $Y\times X$ - together with the usual projections - are both products of $X$ and $Y$ (according to the universal property, a product of $X$ and $Y$ is also a product of $Y$ and $X$).

Comment: Ok, and this is the usual way of doing things. Namely, you construct your object first, then you show that it satisfies a universal property, and then any other object satisfying this universal property is isomorphic to it (and there is a unique isomorphism commuting with the universal maps - here, the projections). For instance, indeed, $X \times Y \cong Y \times X$ (which is true in any category with products,  then).

Comment: What I'm about to say is probably obvious, but I want to be sure there hasn't been a misunderstanding: What bothered me we was the impression that we define the cartesian product and afterwards **re-define**  it by a universal property, which implicitly involves the priorly made definition via the use of functions. However, I don't think this is correct: The cartesian product is always the set of ordered pairs defined in my question, while a product (notice the omission of "cartesian") is only defined up to an isomorphism.

Comment: When a proof involves a product, it should suffice to invoke its universal property. I guess it's easier to work with ordered pairs (tuples), but especially in physics, I think it's conceptually important to keep this distinction in mind.

Comment: As I said, a universal property is not a definition. But it is a characterization, up to a unique isomorphism. And usually, if you have a canonical isomorphism (in the category of sets, a canonical bijection) between two objects, you can consider that they are the same (in our particular situation, all of these objects are "the" (cartesian) product). So making this distinction does not really matter, in fact. Well, you can keep it in mind if you prefer, but you will see that it is not that useful.

Comment: So in fact you can use the universal property and use ordered pairs, both are equally good. At least if you take products of sets ;  products exist in many categories where ordered pairs don't make sense.